# Why does my binary search always return -1

Tags: c, binary-search

I'm quite new to recursive function and is trying to search an id in a struct array, why does it always return -1 instead of 3?

This is the struct

```
struct Student{
  int id;
};

struct Student student[4];
```

My binary search function

```
int binary(int start, int end, int search){
  if(end >= start){
    int mid = (start + (end - start)) / 2;

    if(student[mid].id == search){
      return mid;
    }

    if(search > student[mid].id){
      return binary(mid+1, end, search);
    }
    else{
      return binary(1, mid-1, search);
    }
  }
  else{
    return -1;
  }
```

The main function

````
int main(){
  student[0].id = 1004;
  student[1].id = 1003;
  student[2].id = 1002;
  student[3].id = 1001;

  int position = binary(0, 3, 1001);

  printf("The search value 1001 is at index number %d", position);
}
```
````

Comment: Hmmm `int mid = (start + (end - start)) / 2;` looks wrong.  Perhaps `int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;`?

Comment: The ids are sorted in descending order in your example. Shouldn't it be in ascending order ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have to order the element in ascending order, not descending, so it should be:

```
  student[0].id = 1001;
  student[1].id = 1002;
  student[2].id = 1003;
  student[3].id = 1004;
```

or you have to change the `<` with a `>` on binary function like

```
int binary(int start, int end, int search){
  if(end >= start){
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;

    if(student[mid].id == search){
      return mid;
    }

    if(search < student[mid].id){
      return binary(start, mid-1, search);
    }
    else{
      return binary( mid+1, end,  search);
    }
  }
  else{
    return -1;
  }
}
```

also the index of the recursive call was wrong

Comment: When i try to search 1001, it returns me -1, 1002 returns me the correct one and the others the compiler just crash

Comment: @CheangWaiBin Ask another question.

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes, just end to debug before read your comment... however, i've edited the question with the correct function

Comment: `int mid = start + (start - end) / 2;` has an advantage over `int mid = (start + end) / 2;`: No overflow.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica which overflow? integer max value exceeded?

Comment: Yes, `start + end` can exceed `INT_MAX`.  Not in OP's limited case, but in general.